# Is there a way I can make a react drop down rendered alone

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

Devs in the house.
I'm working on a little project where a user enters his info and on clicking of an action button, a list is to be dropped down for various options. My issue is that when a button is clicked, all the **to-be-dropped-list** are equally affected. and I only want the one whose button was clicked to be dropped down.

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import Action from './action'

const Form = () => {
  document.title = 'Contact Form'
  const [action, setAction] = useState(false)
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState({firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', phone: '',single: '', married: '', student: '', employed: ''})

  const handleChange=(e)=>{
    const name = e.target.name
    const value =e.target.value
    setUser({...user, [name]: value})
    
    // console.log(`Name: ${name} Value: ${value}`);
  }

   var loadFile = function(e){
        var image = document.getElementById('output')
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
      }
  const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
    console.log(12345);
    e.preventDefault()
    if(user.firstName && user.lastName && user.phone){
      const newUser = {...user, time: new Date().getTime().toString()}
      setPeople([...people, newUser])
      // clearing fields
      setUser({firstName: '', lastName: '', phone: '', email: ''})
      // console.log("People :",people,"User: ",user);
      // img
    
    }else{
      console.log("Field cannot be empty");
    }
  }
  const showPpt =(e, index, time)=>{
    console.log('sibling',e.target.nextElementSibling);
    console.log(people);
    people.forEach((a,i)=>{

      if (a.time === time) {
        console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement);
        console.log('old time',a.time, 'btn time',time);
        if (action === true) {
          setAction(false)
        }else if (action === false) {
          setAction(true)
        }

      }
      else{
        console.log('absent');
        console.log('old time',a.time, 'btn time',time);
        // setAction(false)
      }
    })

    // if(time === people[index].time){
    
    // console.log('Index ',index,e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement);
    // console.log('fetch time',people[index].time, 'current time', time);
    // }
    
  }
  return (
    <section>
      <section className="head">
        <h1>hello people</h1>
          <form>
            <section className="inp name">
              <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>          
              <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder='First name' id="firstName" onChange={handleChange} value={user.firstName} />
              <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder='Last name' id="lastName" onChange={handleChange}  value={user.lastName}/>
            </section>
            <section className="inp email">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email" onChange={handleChange} value={user.email} />
              <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
              <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone"  onChange={handleChange} value={user.phone}/>
            </section>
                {/* <section className='inp image'>
              <label htmlFor="file">Image</label>
              <input type="file"  accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" name="image" id="file" style={{display: 'none'}} onChange={loadFile} value={user.fileData}/>   
              <img id='output' style={{width: '5rem'}} />
       
            </section> */}
            <section className="inp Address"></section>
            <div className="radio-btn">
              <section className="inp mrg-status">
              <h4>Relationship</h4>
                <div className="cont">
                  <label htmlFor="single">Single</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="relationship" id="single" onChange={handleChange} value={"single"}/>
                  <label htmlFor="married">Married</label>
                  <input type="radio" name='relationship' id='married' onChange={handleChange} value={"married"}/>
                </div>
              </section>
              <section className="inp employment">
                <h4>Employment</h4>
                <div className="cont">
                  <label htmlFor="student">Student</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="employment" id="student" onChange={handleChange}  value={"employed"} />
                  <label htmlFor="employed">Employed</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="employment" id="employed" onChange={handleChange}  value={"employed"} />
                  
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
            <section className="submit">
              <button className='btn' type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Person</button>

            </section>
          </form>
      </section>
      <section className="main">
        {people.map((data, index)=>{
          const {firstName, lastName, email, phone, relationship, employment, time} = data
          return <article className='user-contact' key={index} {...data}>
            <article className="cont">
              <div className="info">
                <h4>Private information</h4>
                <h4>Name: {firstName} {lastName}</h4>
                <h4>Phone: {phone}</h4>
                <h4>Email: {email}</h4>
                <h4>Relationship status: {relationship}</h4>
                <h4>Employment status: {employment}</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="action">
                <button className='but' onClick={(e)=>showPpt(e, index, time)}>action</button>
                {action && <Action />}
              </div>
            </article>
          </article>
        })}
      </section>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Form
```

Answer (score 0):

That's happen because you deal with an array of `people` with a single boolean state, which populate all the actions of all people.

I suggest you add an extra `field` for each element in `people` array which indicates the `active/unactive` action.

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import Action from './action'

const Form = () => {
  document.title = 'Contact Form'
  const [action, setAction] = useState(false)
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState({firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', phone: '',single: '', married: '', student: '', employed: ''})

  const handleChange=(e)=>{
    const name = e.target.name
    const value =e.target.value
    setUser({...user, [name]: value})
    
    // console.log(`Name: ${name} Value: ${value}`);
  }

   var loadFile = function(e){
        var image = document.getElementById('output')
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
      }
  const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
    console.log(12345);
    e.preventDefault()
    if(user.firstName && user.lastName && user.phone){
      const newUser = {...user, time: new Date().getTime().toString(), active: false}
      setPeople([...people, newUser])
      // clearing fields
      setUser({firstName: '', lastName: '', phone: '', email: ''})
      // console.log("People :",people,"User: ",user);
      // img
    
    }else{
      console.log("Field cannot be empty");
    }
  }
  const showPpt =(e, index, time)=>{
    let personIndex = people.findIndex(a => a.time === time);
    setPeople((prev) => {
       prev[personIndex].active = !prev[personIndex].active
       return [...prev]
    })
  }
  return (
    <section>
      <section className="head">
        <h1>hello people</h1>
          <form>
            <section className="inp name">
              <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>          
              <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder='First name' id="firstName" onChange={handleChange} value={user.firstName} />
              <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder='Last name' id="lastName" onChange={handleChange}  value={user.lastName}/>
            </section>
            <section className="inp email">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email" onChange={handleChange} value={user.email} />
              <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
              <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone"  onChange={handleChange} value={user.phone}/>
            </section>
                {/* <section className='inp image'>
              <label htmlFor="file">Image</label>
              <input type="file"  accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" name="image" id="file" style={{display: 'none'}} onChange={loadFile} value={user.fileData}/>   
              <img id='output' style={{width: '5rem'}} />
       
            </section> */}
            <section className="inp Address"></section>
            <div className="radio-btn">
              <section className="inp mrg-status">
              <h4>Relationship</h4>
                <div className="cont">
                  <label htmlFor="single">Single</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="relationship" id="single" onChange={handleChange} value={"single"}/>
                  <label htmlFor="married">Married</label>
                  <input type="radio" name='relationship' id='married' onChange={handleChange} value={"married"}/>
                </div>
              </section>
              <section className="inp employment">
                <h4>Employment</h4>
                <div className="cont">
                  <label htmlFor="student">Student</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="employment" id="student" onChange={handleChange}  value={"employed"} />
                  <label htmlFor="employed">Employed</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="employment" id="employed" onChange={handleChange}  value={"employed"} />
                  
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
            <section className="submit">
              <button className='btn' type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Person</button>

            </section>
          </form>
      </section>
      <section className="main">
        {people.map((data, index)=>{
          const {firstName, lastName, email, phone, relationship, employment, time} = data
          return <article className='user-contact' key={index} {...data}>
            <article className="cont">
              <div className="info">
                <h4>Private information</h4>
                <h4>Name: {firstName} {lastName}</h4>
                <h4>Phone: {phone}</h4>
                <h4>Email: {email}</h4>
                <h4>Relationship status: {relationship}</h4>
                <h4>Employment status: {employment}</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="action">
                <button className='but' onClick={(e)=>showPpt(e, index, time)}>action</button>
                {action && <Action />}
              </div>
            </article>
          </article>
        })}
      </section>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Form
```